# Expected revenue in an auction

Tags: probability, statistics, auction-theory

> Consider an auction in which two independent buyers bid for an antique object. If each of them draws their valuations from $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ and the auction lets the highest bidder take the object by paying the lowest bid, what's the expected revenue of the auction?

Denote the two buyers' bids by the r.v.s $X, Y \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$.

I think we have to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X | X \geq Y) + \mathbb{E}(Y | Y \geq X)$. When I calculate it, I get $$2 \left(\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} x \cdot \frac{1}{1-y} dydx\right) = 1.5$$

This is incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Please note that I know a possible way to solve this is to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(\min(X,Y))$. But I am trying to figure out where I went wrong with my above method.

Comment: I don't understand what "the auction lets the highest bidder take the object by paying the lowest bid" means.

Comment: You actually need to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(\min\{X,Y\})$

Comment: @SuzuHirose The highest bidder gets to buy the antique object at the lowest auction price. If two bidders independently value the items at say prices $0.1$ and $0.7$, then the person who bid (bade) $0.7$ gets to buy the object at $0.1$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes, but I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think you have to calculate $E(Y|X\geq Y)$ don't you?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Oh right. I have to calculate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a funny auction but why not. The expected revenue is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big[\min(X,Y)\big]&=\textstyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\int_0^yx\,dx\,dy+\int_0^1\int_y^1y\,dx\,dy\\
&=\textstyle\int_0^1\frac{y^2}{2}\,dy+\int_0^1y-y^2\,dy=\int_0^1y-\frac{y^2}{2}\,dy\\
&=\textstyle\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\\[2mm]&=\frac{1}{3}\,.
\end{align}
Alternatively one could use the law of total expectation by which
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big[\min(X,Y)\big]&=
\mathbb E\big[Y1_{\{X\ge Y\}}\big]+\mathbb E\big[X1_{\{Y>X\}}\big]\\[2mm]
&=\underbrace{\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X\ge Y\big]}_{\textstyle=\frac{1}{3}}\,\underbrace{\mathbb P\big\{X\ge Y\big\}}_{\textstyle=\frac{1}{2}}+\underbrace{\mathbb E\big[X\big|Y> X\big]}_{\textstyle=\frac{1}{3}}\,\underbrace{\mathbb P\big\{Y>X\big\}}_{\textstyle=\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\,.
\end{align}
Proof.

Let's calculate the conditional expectations $$\mathbb E[Y|X\ge Y],\quad\mathbb E[Y|Y> X],\quad\mathbb E[X|X\ge Y],\quad\mathbb E[X|Y> X]\,$$
that were discussed in the comments.
From  $\mathbb P\{X\ge Y\}=\mathbb P\{Y>X\}=\frac{1}{2}$ we get
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{Y\le z|X\ge Y\}&=\frac{\int_0^z\int_y^1\,dx\,dy}{1/2}
=2\textstyle\int_0^z1-y\,dy=2z-z^2\,,\\
\mathbb P\{Y\le z|Y>X\}&=\frac{\int_0^z\int_0^y\,dx\,dy}{1/2}
=2\textstyle\int_0^zy\,dy=z^2\,.
\end{align}
Taking the derivative w.r.t. $z$ the conditional PDFs of $Y$ are therefore,
\begin{align}
p(y|X\ge Y)=2-2y\,,\quad p(y|Y>X)=2y\,.
\end{align}
This leads to

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y|X\ge Y]&=\textstyle\int_0^1y(2-2y)\,dy=2-\frac{2}{3}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\,,\tag{1}\\
\mathbb E[Y|Y>X]&=\textstyle\int_0^12y^2\,dy=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}\,,\\
\mathbb E[X|X\ge Y]&=\frac{2}{3}\,,\quad\text{ (by symmetry) }\\
\mathbb E[X|Y>X]&=\frac{1}{3}\,.\quad\text{ (by symmetry) }\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$
***Remarks.***

The proposed solutions in the edited OP, resp. in a recent comment
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E[X|X\ge Y]+\mathbb E[Y|Y> X]=\frac{4}{3}\,,\\
&\mathbb E[Y|X\ge Y]+\mathbb E[X|Y> X]=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
are both wrong
because we add expectations that are conditioned on mutually exclusive events. They are also different from $1/3$ which was mentioned as the correct answer in the OP that got overridden by some edits.

The other proposed solution (1) in a comment equals the correct solution (as well as (2) does) but I think this is a coincidence that is based on the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and on the uniformity of their distributions.

Comment: This is *probably* more common than we think. [Apparently, Google's AdWord uses this and also Facebook.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_second-price_auction). +1 but I am not accepting your answer as I mentioned in the question that I am not looking for this solution.

Comment: @Citrus . In the first version of OP you wrote "The answer is 1/3. Where did I go wrong?" . It starts to become confusing . I am now asking you that same question.

Comment: That's true. I am accepting it but can you tell me if $\mathbb{E}[\text{revenue}] = \mathbb{E}(Y | X \geq Y) + \mathbb{E}(X | Y \geq X)$?

Comment: Done in edit of the answer. @SuzuHirose (you may want to take a look at that).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Very helpful.